# Initialize and save multiple related documents together in nestjs and mongoose

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-mongoose, nestjs-mongodb

[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvDBj.png)

I have attached photos!

Hello, I have the following case: I want to automatically create a user after creating an account and save it to the database. I am using mongoose and nestjs, I have written the following schema:

```
// Account Schema
export type AccountDocument = HydratedDocument<Account>

@Schema()
export class Account {
  // @Prop()
  // id: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true, immutable: true })
  username: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  password: string;

  @Prop({ required: true, default: false, immutable: true })
  isAdmin: boolean;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    unique: true
  })
  user: User;
}

export const AccountSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Account)
```

```
//User schema
export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>

@Schema()
export class User {
  // @Prop()
  // id: string;

  @Prop({ required: false })
  displayName: string;

  @Prop({ required: false })
  address: string;

  @Prop({ required: false })
  phoneNumber: string;

  @Prop({ required: false, enum: genderEnum })
  gender: genderEnum;

  @Prop({ required: false })
  avatar: string;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Account',
    unique: true
  })
  account: Account
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User)
```

I'm trying to find a way to automatically create a user associated with this account when creating an account.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

##### You need to initialize the user property when creating a new Account

Mongoose won't initialize subdocuments if they are **undefined**, but if you set them to **any truthy value** (even an empty object), mongoose will apply the **default values** from the schema to this subdocument.

```
const accountDoc = new Account(...data)
accountDoc.user = {} // <- set this
await accountDoc.save()
console.log(accountDoc.user._id) // <- ObjectID
```

From the docs: [Subdocument defaults](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocument-defaults).